# Angular - Enable button only on line where clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table with some details. My problem is that in one of the columns I have buttons. For example, I click the button on line 0 but all buttons are enabled. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Already tried to pass the line number, but so far unsuccessful :(

**HTML**

```
 <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate'">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn ClassPlay">
        <img src="./assets/play.svg" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'">
        <img src="./assets/playV.svg" *ngIf="currentState=='start'">
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="currentState='start'; startTimer(data, data.rowIndex)">Start</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="currentState='pause'; pauseTimer((data, data.rowIndex)">Pause</a>
      </div>
      <span class="timer">{{display}}</span>
    </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
startTimer(data,row) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display=this.transform( this.time)
    }, 1000);
  }

      transform(value: number): string {
      var sec_num = value; 
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    }

  pauseTimer(data,row) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

**What I Tried**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn ClassPlay">
        <img src="./assets/play.svg" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'">
        <img src="./assets/playV.svg" *ngIf="currentState=='start' && currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex">
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="currentState='start'; startTimer(data)">Start</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start' && currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="currentState='pause'; pauseTimer(data)">Pause</a>
      </div>
      <span class="timer">{{currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex ? display : ''}}</span>



startTimer(data) {
    this.currentRowIndex = data.rowIndex;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display=this.transform( this.time)
    }, 1000);
  }

      transform(value: number): string {
      var sec_num = value; 
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    }

  pauseTimer(data) {
    this.currentRowIndex = data.rowIndex;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

**The only problem now is that when I click the start button all buttons on the other lines disappear and only reappear on the next line.
Time is also wrong, I start the timeline on one line and when I start on the other, the time always keeps adding up and not starting over as it should**

Comment: Do you have only two states (`pause` and `start`)?

Comment: what do you mean by:  I click the button on line 0 but all buttons are enabled.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes

Comment: @c_ogoo 
I have the buttons in each row of the table, when I click the button in the first row only (in start) all buttons start the timer and not just what I clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, 
I can offer this solution.

```
<div *dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate'">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn ClassPlay">
        <img src="./assets/play.svg" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'">
        <img src="./assets/playV.svg" *ngIf="currentState=='start' && currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex">
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="currentState='start'; startTimer(data, data.rowIndex)">Start</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start' && currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex"routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="currentState='pause'; pauseTimer()">Pause</a>
      </div>
      <span class="timer">{{currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex ? display : '00'}}</span>
    </div>
```

and in .ts

```
currentRowIndex = null; // you need to define in your component

startTimer(index) {
    this.currentRowIndex = index;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display=this.transform( this.time)
    }, 1000);
  }

      transform(value: number): string {
      var sec_num = value; 
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    }

  pauseTimer() {
    this.currentRowIndex = null;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: I received this error: Cannot create property '0' on number '0'.  
I updated in the post what I tested. I didn't realize what this.dataArray is

Comment: @Harry ah sorry I copied answer of Lykos94 instead of your question.

Comment: @Harry I have updated my answer please can you try like this

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! The button still runs on all lines and not just the line where it was clicked :(

Comment: @Harry Please can you replace your html with my, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still giving the same, you can see in the post image :(

Comment: apply that  this.currentRowIndex = index.rowIndex; and the green button just appears on the right line, but the timer appears on all :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204187/discussion-between-ashot-aleqsanyan-and-harry).

Comment: @Harry I think you need to do  replace `{{display}}` with `{{currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex ? display : '00'}}`

Comment: @Harry I have updaed the answer, Please have a look at html

Comment: I already solved the display problem when it is paused.
The only problem left is that when I click play all the other buttons disappear :(

Comment: Already updated the post with the remaining problem, thank you for trying to help me

Comment: @Harry here is the stackblitz example please have a look I tried to create the simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nw1uhp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, my assumption is that you are always changing the same variable `currentState`. Once you click the Start button (anchor) the first time like here

```
(click)="currentState='start'; ....//
```

you are setting the *shared* variable `currentState` to the start value. Therefore all the `ngIf` react to it. What you I believe you want to achieve is having something like a boolean value that express the current state for each row in the table.

**Update:** Here is an example of what I think you want to achieve

```html
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="startTimer(data.rowIndex)">Start</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" routerLinkActive="active"
          (click)="pauseTimer()">Pause</a>
      </div>
```

And this should be your **Component.ts**

```js
  public dataArray: Array<DataItem>;
  public timeArray: Array<number>;
  public interval;

  constructor() {
    this.dataArray = // constructor of your data

    // We create an array to keep track of the time for each element
    // and fill the array initially with zeroes
    this.timeArray = new Array(this.dataArray.length).fill(0);
  }

  // We need here to know the index in order to know what timer to increment in the array
  startTimer(rowIndex) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.timeArray[rowIndex]++;
      // The display will always show the current ongoing timer
      this.display=this.transform(this.timeArray[rowIndex])
    }, 1000); 
  }

  pauseTimer(rowIndex) {
    // alert(this.timeArray[rowIndex]) <-- just for test
    clearInterval(this.interval); // Clears the interval
  }
```

**Update  2** From your last update, i believe you want also to show the display for each row. Here how to achieve it

```html
<span class="timer">{{transform(timeArray[rowIndex])}}</span>
```

as you can see I don't use the display variable, but apply your transform function to the value of the `rowIndex`

**Update 3** The solution to the last problem you posted is the following

```html
.. *ngIf="currentState=='start' && currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex"
```

the && is returning true only for the current row, therefore only that one is displayed. Remove it like this

```html
.. *ngIf="currentState=='start'"
```

and to reset the timer for the row when you press pause

```js
pauseTimer(rowIndex) {
    this.timeArray[rowIndex] = 0; // Add this line
    clearInterval(this.interval); // Clears the interval
  }
```

Comment: I have to execute the startTimer function, but it should only be executed on the line where the button was clicked, hence the line number :(

Comment: You are passing the row parameter but you are actually not using it in your functions ```setTimer``` nor ```pauseTimer```

Comment: I think you're right, but I have no idea how I can solve this :(

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it out, I hope it helps :)

Comment: I received this error: Cannot create property '0' on number '0'.  
I updated in the post what I tested. I didn't realize what this.dataArray is

Comment: ```this.dataArray``` is the array of elements you want to display. From my understanding, you are trying to display a start and pause button for each of your ```data in 'cellTemplate'```. The solution I proposed requires knowing how many rows you have in your data. Then it creates an array with length equal to the number of rows, which is indexed by the ```rowIndex```. In this way you can keep a ```time``` counter for each row. In this way you can distinguish among the click in different rows. Am I understanding correctly the problem? Please let me know

Comment: Already updated the post with the remaining problem, thank you for trying to help me